# Can we place RoteConfig.cs in other folder instead of App_Start folder ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i saw Route.config file is located in APP_START folder but i like to know is it mandatory to store Route.config file in APP_START folder?

if yes then please explain in details why do we need to store Route.config file in APP_START folder? can we store Route.config file in other folder or in root folder?

One guy said it is possible but you need to write extra code for use the configuration. i just like to know out of curiosity what code i need to write to put Route.config file in other location. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could write anywhere you want. It is just simple configuration. But you must make sure your configuration is called by `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs` file. If you look at that method you can see `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` is called. You could call your own configuration method or even configure your routing directly there.